# VBA select onclick if condition is met

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

```
<tr> align = "center" onmouseover = "this.style.cursor='pointer';" onclick = "__doPostBack('ctl01$PortalContent$GridOrderControl1$CILGridViewOrder','Select$0')">
<td rowSpan = "1" colSpan = "1">new</td>
<td rowSpan = "1" colSpan = "1">Text2</td>
<td rowSpan = "1" colSpan = "1">Text3</td>
<td rowSpan = "1" colSpan = "1">Text4</td>
<td rowSpan = "1" colSpan = "1">Text5</td>
```

Hi, I need help for the above. What I want:
1) check if first row is new and "text 4" didn't appear before
2) if the above condition is met, click/select on the onclick
3) Select$0 is the first row in the table, there are 10 rows in total, I want to check all rows then click and do something else when the conditions are met

So far i am able to pinpoint the text out, however i cant call this onclick event, any idea on how to do it?

What I have so far

```
Set Data = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(6).getElementsByTagName("tr")
x = 1
y = 1

For Each eleCollection in Data
  If Instr(1, eleCollection.innerHTML, "Select$0") >0 Then
    For Each ele in eleCollection.getElementsByTagName("td")
       ws.Cells(x,y).Value = ele.innerText
       y = y + 1
       x = x + 1
    Next
  End If
Next elemCollection
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You're neither asking any questions nor saying what your exact problem is. The code you have posted seems to have been written by someone who knows what they're doing. Do you know what this code does (and how..)? Also, the 1st condition you're talking about is not very clear (to me at least). Could you rephrase?

Comment: Apart from what @StavrosJon has written... You should at least increment x, so you don't write everything in the same row.

Comment: @StavrosJon what i meant was the 1st condition is to verify if its either new or completed, sorry i didnt specify properly. I cant seem to get my code to go to Select$0 only, and click this event if the conditions are met. the above code allows me to pinpoint all Select$0 to Select$10 and print out all value within it, but i cant select specifically select$0 onclick event.

Comment: @Zwenn i added the increment for x and y afterwards, no worries about that. There is no Id to pinpoint this so i am not sure how to go to this directly.

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if the text in the first `<td>` is "new"? Please edit your question to restate it instead of explaining in the comment. It makes us confused. Have you tried any code to check the condition? Does any error occur in your code?

Comment: The condition is still unclear. Also, judging from the code you've shown us, it seems to me, you know how to refer to elements even if there's no ID. For example to get the 1st `td` element of every `tr` you would do something like `eleCollection.getElementsByTagName("td")(0)`.

Comment: SImilarly, to get the first `tr` element you would do `IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")(6).getElementsByTagName("tr")(0)`

Comment: You can use `.Click` function to click the `<tr>` you want. As you have already found out the `<tr>` containing "Select$0" and you want to click "Select$0", you just need to use `eleCollection.Click` in your loop. If my understanding is wrong, please provide more related html codes of the page you want to automate, so that we can have a better understanding of the issue.